# Error when installing ClickOnce application

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-studio, deployment, clickonce

Today I started getting an error everytime a user tries to install the aplication, I dunno why im getting this after months of 0 problems with the deployment, I havent change anything related to the project properties, all the modifications has been code related.

**Here is the error log**

> PLATFORM VERSION INFO
>     Windows             : 10.0.15063.0 (Win32NT)
>     Common Language Runtime     : 4.0.30319.42000
>     System.Deployment.dll       : 4.7.2046.0 built by: NET47REL1
>     clr.dll             : 4.7.2101.1 built by: NET47REL1LAST
>     dfdll.dll           : 4.7.2046.0 built by: NET47REL1
>     dfshim.dll          : 10.0.15063.0 (WinBuild.160101.0800)
>
> SOURCES
>     Deployment url          : file:///Y:/RE/RentaEquipos.application
>     Deployment Provider url     : file://svrre/Repository/RE/RentaEquipos.application
>     Application url         : file://svrre/Repository/RE/Application%20Files/RentaEquipos_2017_07_10_8/RentaEquipos.exe.manifest
>
> IDENTITIES
>     Deployment Identity     : RentaEquipos.application, Version=2017.7.10.8, Culture=es-CR, PublicKeyToken=0000000000000000, processorArchitecture=x86
>
> APPLICATION SUMMARY
>     * Installable application.
>
> ERROR SUMMARY
>     Below is a summary of the errors, details of these errors are listed later in the log.
>     * Activation of Y:\RE\RentaEquipos.application resulted in exception. Following failure messages were detected:
>         + Specified cast is not valid.
>
> COMPONENT STORE TRANSACTION FAILURE SUMMARY
>     No transaction error was detected.
>
> WARNINGS
>     * The manifest for this application does not have a signature. Signature validation will be ignored.
>     * The manifest for this application does not have a signature. Signature validation will be ignored.
>     * The manifest for this application does not have a signature. Signature validation will be ignored.
>
> OPERATION PROGRESS STATUS
>     * [26/7/2017 11:23:16] : Activation of Y:\RE\RentaEquipos.application has started.
>     * [26/7/2017 11:23:16] : Processing of deployment manifest has successfully completed.
>     * [26/7/2017 11:23:16] : Installation of the application has started.
>
> ERROR DETAILS
>     Following errors were detected during this operation.
>     * [26/7/2017 11:23:16] System.InvalidCastException
>         - Specified cast is not valid.
>         - Source: System.Deployment
>         - Stack trace:
>             at System.Deployment.Application.DownloadManager.VerifyRequestedPrivilegesSupport(String requestedExecutionLevel)
>             at System.Deployment.Application.DownloadManager.DownloadApplicationManifest(AssemblyManifest deploymentManifest, String targetDir, Uri deploymentUri, > IDownloadNotification notification, DownloadOptions options, Uri& appSourceUri, String& appManifestPath)
>             at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.DownloadApplication(SubscriptionState subState, ActivationDescription actDesc, Int64 transactionId, > TempDirectory& downloadTemp)
>             at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.InstallApplication(SubscriptionState& subState, ActivationDescription actDesc)
>             at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.PerformDeploymentActivation(Uri activationUri, Boolean isShortcut, String textualSubId, String > deploymentProviderUrlFromExtension, BrowserSettings browserSettings, String& errorPageUrl, Uri& deploymentUri)
>             at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.PerformDeploymentActivationWithRetry(Uri activationUri, Boolean isShortcut, String textualSubId, String > deploymentProviderUrlFromExtension, BrowserSettings browserSettings, String& errorPageUrl)
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>             at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
>             at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.PerformDeploymentActivationWithRetry(Uri activationUri, Boolean isShortcut, String textualSubId, String > deploymentProviderUrlFromExtension, BrowserSettings browserSettings, String& errorPageUrl)
>             at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.ActivateDeploymentWorker(Object state)
>
> COMPONENT STORE TRANSACTION DETAILS
>     No transaction information is available.

Comment: Since it's `System.Deployment.Application.DownloadManager.VerifyRequestedPrivilegesSupport(String requestedExecutionLevel)` that's throwing the `InvalidCastException`, I'd say it's a good guess to say that the `requestedExecutionLevel` being used for the download is invalid.  Perhaps there's something wrong in your config?

Comment: Tested a second aplication im installing with clickonce and it gives me the same error, also this second aplications was updated months ago and also it olny gives the error to me in windows 10, tested other computer with windows 7 and both aplications install without problems, but theres a second problem, if I deploy an update for the app the installer gets the problems in any operating system, dunno what could be happening with this

Comment: Unfortunately, the code for that `DownloadManager` class isn't available on [Reference Source](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/), so that makes it difficult to figure out what exactly it's doing.  I guess if you were really desperate, you might try decompiling `System.Deployment.dll`

Comment: actually it is, found it http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Deployment/System/Deployment/Application/DownloadManager.cs,ae071c428d1d5e9b

Comment: Well, yeah, but that seems to just be the stubbed out signature, not the actual code.

Comment: ok, got the code using jetbrains decompiler and I got this https://codeshare.io/5w4Aj9

Comment: Aha!  Nice.  So, it looks like the culprit is the `if ((int) registryKey.GetValue("EnableLUA") != 0)` statement.  So, that `registryKey` was read from `\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System` in the windows registry.  For it to throw that exception, that key must exist and it must have an `EnableLUA` value, but it must be typed as something other than an integer.  Try running `RegEdit.exe` on that machine, navigate to that key, and inspect that value to see what it is.

Comment: It should say `REG_DWORD` in the `Type` column for that value

Comment: OMFG! got there and the key was a REG_SZ, deleted it and created like DWORD, it's working now, but why did it changed its type? checked in another computer and it was DWORD how you said, checked if deploying another update would reverse this, and it didnt, so by now everything seems to be working. Thanks a lot! 15/10 Would be in trouble again!!!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `DownloadManager.VerifyRequestedPrivilegesSupport` method is throwing an `InvalidCastException`.  Unfortunately, the code for that class is not available on [ReferenceSource](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/), but when `System.Deployment.dll` is [decompiled](https://codeshare.io/5w4Aj9), the culprit is clear.  The decompiled method looks like this:

```cs
private static void VerifyRequestedPrivilegesSupport(string requestedExecutionLevel)
{
  Logger.AddMethodCall("VerifyRequestedPrivilegesSupport(" + requestedExecutionLevel + ") called.");
  if (!PlatformSpecific.OnVistaOrAbove)
    return;
  bool flag = false;
  RegistryKey registryKey = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey("Software\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Policies\\System");
  if (registryKey != null && registryKey.GetValue("EnableLUA") != null)
  {
    Logger.AddInternalState("LUA policy key = " + registryKey.Name);
    if ((int) registryKey.GetValue("EnableLUA") != 0)
    {
      flag = true;
      Logger.AddInternalState("LUA is enabled.");
    }
  }
  if (flag && (string.Compare(requestedExecutionLevel, "requireAdministrator", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) == 0 || string.Compare(requestedExecutionLevel, "highestAvailable", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) == 0))
    throw new InvalidDeploymentException(ExceptionTypes.UnsupportedElevetaionRequest, string.Format((IFormatProvider) CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture, Resources.GetString("Ex_ManifestExecutionLevelNotSupported"), new object[0]));
}
```

The line that throws the exception would be this one:

```cs
if ((int) registryKey.GetValue("EnableLUA") != 0)
```

The code reads registry key `\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersio‌​n\Policies\System` from the windows registry.  For it to throw that exception, the key must exist and it must have an `EnableLUA` value, but the value must be typed as something other than an integer.  You need to run `RegEdit.exe` on the machine that's getting the error, navigate to that key in the registry, and inspect that value to see what it is.  It should show `REG_DWORD` in the `Type` column for that value.  If not, delete it and re-add it with the right type.

Comment: That's it!, after two days of googling and reading usless posts this finally helped, thanks.

Comment: Anyone have any idea how EnableLUA might be created as REG_SZ?